According to scripture, in what sense are believers meant to be ‘accountable’ to a local church group?
I have often heard it said that believers need to be members of a local church in order to be ‘accountable’. I am assuming all believers understand that they should regularly fellowship with a local church. My question is not about that.
My question is from the scripture in what sense might this accountability mean? I am not sure  the word accountable is actually used in the New Testament except that the whole world is accountable to God by the Law but I take it to mean in certain situations some form of answerable agreement of conduct, or something along that line is implied by various bible verses which make people chose the word ‘accountable’ as though people were accountants making some kind of record or enforcement of some basic standard.
What does it actually mean? What are its limits? What sense does the scripture support or limit such a concept?

Off the top of my head, I've got Galatians 6:1-10 and James 5:16,19-20. I Corinthians 4-6 also seems relevant, and the apparently related passage in 2 Cor. 1:22-2:11.

@JedSchaaf - that’s a good start. Answering questions very well is quite difficult because we essentially need to gather some of the relevant scriptures and then interpret them in a way that does not contradict any other scripture making a mini-systematic-theology personalized to the question. I recommend taking your time and hammer down one for a topic you find interesting enough to put in the sweat. When my life affords the time I find it personally rewarding even when nobody notices the answer.

None of the above is appropriate to scripture. The question has not used any scriptural language nor has it mentioned the absolute necessities of Christianity - repentance, faith, baptism (into One Body) the Headship of Christ, the service of sons, the love of the  brethren, union with Christ, the fellowship of the apostles' doctrine, and communion with all saints. I would not be able to even begin to answer it without fundamentally adjusting every single sentence. Downvoted -1. The question expresses what is deeply, deeply wrong with denominational Christianity.

@Nigel - No worries am pretty sure if I answer my own question you will upvote the answer ;)

Mike, thanks, and I fully agree with you about fully investigating a topic. I just left a comment instead of a full answer because I wanted to note something down for others to start with, and I didn't have much time to write. I'll make a more complete answer soon.

I have upvoted for the same reasons that Nigel downvoted: I've heard this talk about "accountability", and I agree that it expresses something deeply wrong with denominationalism. I think the anwer will be a frame challenge of some sort.

"Soon" was apparently 15 days. :P

The question states as a starting point that church members ought to meet together regularly, so I won't need to go into a defense of assembling. And I won't defend whether believers are accountable to God; I think that's already abundantly clear from Scripture. Additionally, I think it's fairly clear that sticking to an agreement to submit oneself to a particular leadership falls under maintaining honesty (Romans 12:17).
The point in question that I will answer here is whether members of a church are accountable in some way to each other. I contend that all members are accountable to each other to various degrees, and furthermore, that it is one of the main practical reasons to have a specific, official list of members in a local gathering.
First, accountability requires submission. Ephesians 5:21 gives a general command to Christians to submit to one another (which is itself a subcommand of either "be filled with the Spirit" from verse 18 or "walk circumspectly" from verse 15). Paul goes on to describe what that submission looks like in several types of scenarios in the rest of chapter 5 and the beginning of chapter 6.
Now, someone could argue that the command to submit in Ephesians 5-6 applies only to those specific interactions, but then James 5:16 goes beyond that and gives the commands to "confess your faults" to one another and to pray for each other. Galatians 6:1-10 also directs spiritual believers to restore others who are overtaken in a fault (but with caution so as to avoid being tempted themselves) and to bear one another's burdens. I think it should be clear that someone cannot be "restored" if they're unwilling and not submissive to the others' attempts, so they do have some measure of accountability here as well.
We have more specific commands and examples in I Corinthians chapters 4-6. Among various commands concerning moral purity, Paul gives an example of a man who was revealed to be living indulgently in a sin so atrocious that even unbelievers thought it abominable, and he directs the church to expel him, as well as any others who are similarly living unrepentantly in sin. Then in II Corinthians 1:22-2:11, Paul appears to readdress the situation, where the church had expelled this man, but he had repented, and so Paul instructs them to accept him back into the fold; the purpose of expulsion was (eventual) restoration for joy and comfort, and to avoid giving Satan a foothold in dividing the church. This man effectively was held accountable to and by the rest of the church.
In essence, individual accountability to others within a local church is simply church discipline/encouragement with a reversed perspective. If the local church's responsibility is to keep the assembly pure (the apparent purpose of church discipline per I and II Corinthians), then each individual member's responsibility is to grow spiritually so as to avoid needing discipline by keeping themselves pure, to be able to encourage each other, and to be qualified to assist with those who may need discipline.
Finally, the application to church polity: if a church has no official membership (or an open or loose membership, which effectively amounts to the same thing), then it cannot put anyone out of the assembly (as there is no "inside" or "outside" for that group). That eliminates the very possibility of restoring them after they have come to the end of themselves and have realized for themselves their need to rely on Christ and the love offered within a church's fellowship, as the prodigal son in Jesus' parable eventually realized how much his father loved him.

good answer. glad you put your thoughts together I accept it leaving my own answer to make balance when for membership is made under compulsion rather then freely according to individual faith. (see my supplementary answer)

I also think sometimes we forget how before cars the local church was a real community, everyone one each other well. There was no opportunity to drop into churches anonymously without social implications outside. Especially in biblical times it was more like a close knit  family that would make accountability to each other a lot more natural. Personally I would not make the membership necessarily formal (although formal is fine) so long as the members get to know each other well. Knowing each other well voluntarily and being responsible to treat each other in love, is the main thrust of it.

@Mike Even before cars, accountability and church membership issues are and have been a significant problem. (See the controversy concerning the Half-Way Covenant in colonial America.) (There is also in my local area a church with their only membership requirement being attending Sunday services twice; they were easily taken over by a cult-like faction from a different church split who quickly split that church, too. Formal membership would have prevented that.)

I’ve been a Christian for almost 30 years and I have never heard any Christian say believers are meant to be accountable to a local church group.
Christians are accountable to God, not to any denomination, or church, or group, or individual. Membership to a church and association with fellow Christians is desirable but nowhere in Scripture does it say we are held accountable to any organisation.
Jesus said this in Matthew 12:36:

Men will have to give account on the day of judgment for every careless word they have spoken.

This is supported in Romans 14:12 where it says:

Each of us will give an account of himself to God.

God is our judge and Hebrews 4:13 gives this stern warning:

everything is uncovered and laid bare before the eyes of him to whom we must give account.

Romans 3:19-20 is more emphatic when it addresses everyone who is under the law and says the whole world is held accountable:

Everything is uncovered and laid bare before the eyes of him to whom we must give account.

No-one can be declared righteous in God’s sight by observing the law. The law makes us conscious of sin and the law condemns us because we cannot keep it.
There is one sense in which church members can be held accountable to those who are responsible for preaching, teaching and discipling those who are under their care.  If they have signed up to agreeing to specific codes of conduct, morality, and the like and they then break that agreement, the church leaders should show them the error of their ways. This is covered in Galatians 6:1-10.
If a church member is unrepentant and continues to blatantly go against God’s laws (for example, morality) or the laws of the land (criminal conduct), then such persons may be thrown out. But that should only ever be done in dire circumstances when every effort to bring such a person to their senses had failed. See 1 Corinthians chapters 5 and 6.

+1 for grappling with the issues in what I would imagine as instinctively in the right direction

From my own research I think the main idea of church accountability and its limits can be found in this verse:
Hebrews 13:17
English Standard Version

17 Obey your leaders and submit to them, for they are keeping watch
over your souls, as those who will have to give an account. Let them
do this with joy and not with groaning, for that would be of no
advantage to you.

Now, this presets a crucial point in church doctrine, for clearly Christianity is entirely lost if we interpret this to mean a submission that does not include our own faith in the truthfulness of what the leaders preach. It presumes the faithfulness of the leaders to preach and instruct according to the truth. Under this assumption submitting to them is the same as submitting to God, for we are simply submitting to our own faith. However if a leader no longer preaches the truth, or to the degree that the depart from the truth we can’t submit in our duty to our own conscience and to God.  This is a spiritual submission where to the degree that our leaders proclaim the gospel to us in purity, we are naturally encouraged and our submission to them is simply gratitude to God for supporting our faith in its needful support of such a ministry.
However there seems implied more than just spiritual submission (or rather submission to God in the benefits of the ministry of others) it also respects the office of one having authority over us in a social situation or title.
Romans ESV

13:1 Let every person be subject to the governing authorities. For
there is no authority except from God, and those that exist have been
instituted by God. 2 Therefore whoever resists the authorities resists
what God has appointed, and those who resist will incur judgment.

The above verse in not speaking about the church but civil authorities in the world. However the principle has some cross-over because in a church there is some external order held by its leaders and even when we disagree and can’t submit in our conscience, for non essential matters, we may still respect the organization in humility. This is a respect of the office not dependent on spiritual respect of the person. For matters not directly related to the free exercise of our faith, we should also be willing to submit for the sake of peace. This is just what we might call common courtesy.
In conclusion we only are accountable to God and our own conscience, otherwise the gospel is destroyed. However, when our faith is supported by leaders and teachers, we will and we ought to thankfully submit to their ministry. When this is not fully possible due to the obvious neglect of preachers or teachers in their duties to God, we still may have respect for the office they hold as an overall submission to the organizations that we benefit from and give ourselves to. In the extreme case, when the duty of pastors and teachers is neglected to the point of introducing heresies, we have a duty to remove ourselves from their assemblies and find a better church.
